# Display all information by typing id in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get name and surname of array by typing id in input field. This is my array:

```
{id: 1, name: 'Jon', surname: 'Doe'},
{id: 2, name: 'Ted', surname: 'Doe'},
{id: 3, name: 'James', surname: 'Jordan'}
```

**How it should look**

[image: How it should look]

onHandleCurretUser

```
onHandleCurrentUser(userId){
    const data = {userId: userId}
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user",{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(result =>{
        this.setState({
            isLoaded:false,
            currentUser:result
        })
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e))
}
```

What I achieved is that you can hard code one value to your button in this example it's id:1 value. It will always display hard coded value.

```
<input type="number" name="userId"/>
<button onClick={e => this.onHandleCurrentUser(1)}>Show user</button>
<div>
    {
        currentUser && <div>{currentUser.name}{currentUser.surname}</div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Try it with async function.
Like onHandleCurrentUser = async(userId) => { if(userId){... fetch the user data }]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to access the value of the `input` element whenever the `button` is clicked. You can do this by making the `input` element a [`controlled component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), meaning that value of the `input` element will be driven by the state of the component.

This way, you can use the value of the `input` when `button` is clicked and you can pass the `input` value to the `this.onHandleCurrentUser` method.

To make the `input` element a controlled component, make the following changes in your component:

1. Add a key-value pair in the `state` that will represent the value of the `input` element

   ```
   this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
   }
   ```
2. Set the value of the `value` attribute of the `input` element equal to the state value created in step 1.

   ```
   <input type="number" name="userId" value={this.state.inputValue}/>
   ```
3. Add a `onChange` event handler that will update the `state` when the `input` value is changed.

   ```
   handleChange = (event) => {
       const { value } = event.target;
       this.setState({ inputValue: value });
   }
   ```

   and set this method as a event handler of the `onChange` event on the `input` element.

   ```
   <input
      type="number"
      name="userId"
      value={this.state.inputValue}
      onChange={this.handleChanage}
   />
   ```

Now you can change the event handler function of `onClick` event on the `button` element to use the value of the `input` element from the `state`.

```
<button 
   onClick={e => this.onHandleCurrentUser(this.state.inputValue)}
>
  Show user
</button>
```

or you could just use the `input` value from the `state` directly in the `this.onHandleCurrentUser` method and just pass a reference of `this.onHandleCurrentUser` method to the `onClick` event

```
<button onClick={this.onHandleCurrentUser}>Show user</button>
```

Comment: You also need to add `onChange={this.handleChange}` to your `<input />` component :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not pass anything in onHandleCurrentUser() and instead use getElementByid().value to get the value of the input box and use that id to create a data variable.

```
<input type="number" name="userId" id="ID"/>
<button onClick={e => this.onHandleCurrentUser()}>Show user</button>

onHandleCurrentUser(){
var inputVal = document.getElementById("ID").value;
const data = {userId: parseInt(inputVal,10)}//Convert string to int
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/user",{
    method:'POST',
    headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(res=> res.json())
.then(result =>{
    this.setState({
        isLoaded:false,
        currentUser:result
    })
})
.catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

}

Comment: It is not good practice to directly manipulate DOM in React. So you shouldn't be using ```getElementById``` in react